# How to test Soap Service on Django with Spyne with Zeep

Tags: django, unit-testing, soap, serversocket, zeep

i trying to using zeep on django to make test to a SOAP service (using Spyne), but always need to be running a runserver, but need to be executed without runserver because need to using a test database not a default database.

i using like like this:

```
def test_obtenerListaAcciones(self):
    # get actions
    # this server need to be up to work, but need to be execute test without work this.
    wsdl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/soap/getactions/'
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    headerArr = {}
    settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True,
                        extra_http_headers=headerArr, raw_response=True)
    client = Client(wsdl,
                    settings=settings)
    action = self.test_create_actions()
    requestData = {
    }
    res = client.service.getactions(**requestData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I has solve using the same client of server that not need to use other like Zeep, only a client of Spyne.

the solution are here:

> https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/spyne/test/interop/test_django.py

and this method is perfect integrated with DJango here:

```
from spyne.client.django import DjangoTestClient
```